# Replacing a listing with another listing in a single frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, overlays

I want to divide my slide to two parts, right and left. `\item First point` appears at the same time as "the first piece of code." Then `\item Second point` appears at the same time as "the second piece of code.", and "the first piece of code" disappears. The following is my MWE of what I want using two frames, but I'm wondering how to do it in a single frame.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Manual}
        \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth]
            \column<1>{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,
                basicstyle=\scriptsize]
The first piece of code.
            \end{lstlisting}
            \column{.45\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<1> First item
                    \item<0> Second item
                \end{itemize}
            \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Manual}
        \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth]
            \column<1>{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,
                basicstyle=\scriptsize]
The second piece of code.
            \end{lstlisting}
            \column{.45\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<1> First item
                    \item<1> Second item
                \end{itemize}
            \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your listing in an `onlyenv`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Manual}
        \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth]
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,
                basicstyle=\scriptsize]
The first piece of code.
            \end{lstlisting}
            \end{onlyenv}
            \begin{onlyenv}<2>
            \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,
                basicstyle=\scriptsize]
The second piece of code.
            \end{lstlisting}
            \end{onlyenv}     
            \end{column}      
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<1-> First item
                    \item<2-> Second item
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
         \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]